# How to write object oriented tasks for python Invoke?

Tags: python, fabric

[Fabric 1](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/usage/tasks.html#new-style-tasks) provides a way to write class based tasks. Here is an example

```
from fabric.tasks import Task
from fabric.api import local

class FooTask(Task):
    def run(self):
        local("ls")
```

I am beginning to transition to using Fabric 2 and would like to port my tasks to Invoke using classes. Can that be done?

Comment: What have you tried or researched so far?

Comment: I've searched the Github issues, the docs, and SO but have unable to turn anything up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell `Invoke` does not support this. The solution for me was to use [Fabric 3](https://github.com/mathiasertl/fabric/) which is a drop-in replacement for the original Fabric.